# Spring Security - 405 Request Method 'POST' Not Supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have implemented Spring Security to my project, but I am getting status 405 when I try to log in. I have already added `csrf` token in the `form`.

This is the error I am getting when I send username and password: 
`HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported`

Spring version: 4.0.2.RELEASED

```
<div class="login-form">
    <c:url var="loginUrl" value="/login" />
    <form action="${loginUrl}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
        <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <p>Invalid username and password.</p>
            </div>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${param.logout != null}">
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                <p>You have been logged out successfully.</p>
            </div>
        </c:if>
        <div class="input-group input-sm">
            <label class="input-group-addon" for="username">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username"
                name="clientusername" placeholder="Enter Username" required>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group input-sm">
            <label class="input-group-addon" for="password">
                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
            </label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password"
                name="clientpassword" placeholder="Enter Password" required>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
            value="${_csrf.token}" />

        <div class="form-actions">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-default"
                value="Log in">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Security Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("G2BUserDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
        .usernameParameter("clientusername").passwordParameter("clientpassword")
        .and().csrf()
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");
//        .and().csrf().disable();
    }
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView loginPage() {
    return new ModelAndView("login");
}

@RequestMapping(value="/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String logoutPage (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (auth != null){    
        new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
    }
    return "redirect:/login?logout";
}

 @RequestMapping(value = "/Access_Denied", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView accessDeniedPage(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", getPrincipal());
        return new ModelAndView("accessDenied");
    }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView adminPage(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", getPrincipal());
        return new ModelAndView("admin");
    }

 private String getPrincipal(){
        String userName = null;
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            userName = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
        } else {
            userName = principal.toString();
        }
        return userName;
    }
```

Almost every topic about this issue says that we need to add `csrf` token, but I already added. Am I missing something?

Comment: Does it work if you disable csrf? Have you tested that? Because from what it seems, there is no endpoint being detected for `/login` that takes a `POST` request. The one you have currently as `GET` is okay for showing the login page, but where is the processing url?

Comment: @px It doesn't. Should I create one more request mapping for the processing url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set two endpoints for one url. But you cannot set any request parameter as required. As I saw your request map for login, you can set your request method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
public ModelAndView loginPage() {
    return new ModelAndView("login");
}
```

Comment: But the Post /login is supposed to check the authentication not returning the view !

Comment: Where happens the authentication in this case?

Comment: If I add RequestMethod.POST as a second end point then login functionality is not working.

Comment: @Moumita Can you please show errors if you are getting and what you have done so far?

Answer (score 12):

First of all `csrf` is [enabled by default](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-configure) in Spring as of Spring 4.0 so there no need to explicitly enable it yourself.

Secondly, there is no endpoint for you to authenticate your login. What you're doing is sending a request to `/login` which only takes a `GET` request. You could create another controller method to receive that `POST` request and authenticate or you could use a `UserDetailsService`.

#### SecurityConfiguration

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/login-form")
                        .anonymous()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/user-login") 
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin", true) // the second parameter is for enforcing this url always
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                    .failureUrl("/user-login")
                    .permitAll();
}

@Autowired 
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;  

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    BCryptPasswordEncoder pe = new  BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(pe);
}
```

Here our view page is `/user-login` and the processing url is `/login` this means in your controller you need remove the mapping for `/login` and add the following:

#### Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user-login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView loginForm() {
    return new ModelAndView("login-form");
}
```

And change your view.

#### View (login-form.jsp)

```
<c:url value="/login" var="loginUrl"/>
<form action="${loginUrl}" method="post" modelAttribute="user">
    Username: <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder=""><br>
    Password: <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder=""><br>

    <input type="hidden"
    name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
    value="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Just as a side note. Using `.successForwardUrl(...)` doesn't have the same effect as using `.defaultSuccessUrl(...)`. The first one will lead to the error the question was describing, while the second one is the right one.

Answer (score 10):

I started getting the same thing when I added a `successForwardUrl` and found that the response on sucessful login is a POST to that endpoint or to "/" if not set.  Once I enabled POST on the defined endpoint as well as GET all was fine.

Answer (score 2):

Check your web.xml file you might forgot to keep "securityFilterChain"

Use this code in web.xml file

```
<!-- Security configuration goes here -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling for a POST yet have only defined GET methods.  Change your endpoint to RequestMethod.POST

Comment: Then how can I enter login page if I change it to POST?

Comment: If you are using the same URI to render the view, create a second endpoint to handle the POST.  You can define the same URI for each of the HTTP verbs

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JSP/JSTL

Change

```
<form action="${loginUrl}" method="post"></form>
```

to

```
<form:form action="${loginUrl}" method="post" </form:form>
```

with tag declaration

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
```

solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the Spring Security filter chain is registered.

With Java configuration, this can be done by creating a class that extends [`AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#abstractsecuritywebapplicationinitializer).

```java
public class SecurityWebInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

Alternatively, edit web.xml and add the following code. (See the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-web-xml).)

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```