# Adding CSRF tokens to my form causes Request method 'POST' not supported error

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, csrf

Spring Version: I am using spring security 3.2(its lame to use older version I know) but I have to work on the old code base.

Problem: If I add Csrf tokens to my form submissions using the default  tag in spring-security file, it causes Request Method 'POST' not supported error.

I have tried disabling the csrf tokens the application works fine. The problem only occurs when i enable csrf tokens.

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42206998/spring-security-405-request-method-post-not-supported

Comment: I gave a look at the mentioned question, my code satisfies all the solution given in that link. I have checked the request types i have declared in the controller. Have correctly mapped to the POST type.

Comment: Note: There is one tab in my application i.e. to fetch messages for a particular user. If I go to that tab and then try to access any other tab after I have visited messages I get this error..

Comment: Check if Spring is creating a new CSRF token once you navigate to the new tab.

Comment: Well I found out that it wasn't because of the CSRF.....sometimes its misleading while debugging the code. And that was the case with me. The reason I was getting the Request not allowed was because of the request header(content-type).